# Python скрипт как windows Service

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Пытаюсь создать небольшой сервис, для сервера Windows 2012 R2, на питоне и столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами. За основу для скелета взят шаблон который очень распространен в инете.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import threading
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import time

class AppServerSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "tstsrvc"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                          (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()
        win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)

    def main(self):
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 9666))
        sock.listen(1)

        def action(client_socket):
            client_socket.send('Hello ! You are connected to {0}'.format(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()).encode())
            client_socket.close()

        while True:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if data:
                threading.Thread(target=lambda: action(conn), daemon=True).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(AppServerSvc)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Собираю этот скрипт в exe файл и пытаюсь поставить на сервер.

```
sc create tstsrvс start= auto type= own DisplayName= "Test Service" binPath= "%systemroot%\tstsrvc.exe"
>>>[SC] CreateService: успех
```

Сервис ставиться, я его запускаю и он работает. Но после перезагрузки, сервис стартует, поработает пару секунд и выключается. В чем может быть причина ?

Сам по себе сервер является терминальным. И я так понимаю надо сервис устанавливать с типом "**share**", но когда я так делаю, при старте службы мне выдается ошибка:

```
"Ошибка 1083: Исполняемая программа, запуск которой настроен в службе, не включена в состав службы."
```

Питон на сервер не установлен, поэтому и собираю сервис в **.exe**.

Comment: А у этого exe зависимости есть?

Comment: @VTT, нету. В моменте после перезагрузки, если к нему обратиться он отработает, но позже все-таки отключится.